# How to merge code and resolve conflicts more easily using git?

Tags: git, merge, conflict

There is a great option `--patch` which can be used with `git add`.

Using this option I can easily review all my changes and decide which chunks should be added to staging area. This interactive process can be made through all modified files.

I am looking for something similar for resolving conflicts. After `rebase` or `merge` you will often get list of `both modified` files.

Is there any command which:

1) will help me iterate through all this `both modified` files? This is very annoying when I have to copy every path to file to manually open it.

2) will resolve all conflicts automagically always using HEAD/main version?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After years of searching, I finally found solution to my problem! It is not perfect, and for sure this is not resolving all my problems, but definitely this speeds up my work!

It is called [git imerge](https://github.com/mhagger/git-imerge) (incremental merge).

At first, this is a little overwhelming and seems complicated, but the idea standing behind incremental merge is very simple.

For sure, you should take a look on [git-imerge presentation from the GitMerge 2013 conference (20 min)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FMZ2_-Ny_zc).

If you prefer read text, here is [git-imerge: A Practical Introduction](http://softwareswirl.blogspot.com/2013/05/git-imerge-practical-introduction.html)

Answer (score 3):

You should have a look to the [git mergetool](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-mergetool.html) that should be of help resolving conflicts through command line.

Answer (score 2):

Try [p4merge](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=[git]+p4merge). You can easily configure it to work with `mergetool` and interactively choose which version do you prefer.